# Applied Algebra Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

No answers please, hints only.

I must prove, by induction, that $$(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\cdots >(1-a_n) > 1-a_1-a_2-\cdots-a_n$$ for real numbers $0<a_i<1$ and integers $n\geq 2$.

My attempt:

Proof. Induction
Basis case: \begin{align} (1-a_1)(1-a_2)&>1-a_1-a_2  \\ 1-a_2-a_1+a_1a_2 &> 1-a_1-a_2 \\ a_1a_2 &> \text{ since } 0<a_i<10 \end{align}
Induction: Assume $P(n)$ holds. Then $$(1-a_1)\cdots(1-a_n)(1-a_{n+1})>1-a_1-a_2-\cdots - a_n-a_{n+1}$$

I'm unable to find a way to use $P(n)$ to show that $P(n+1)$ is true. At this point I am stuck.

Comment: call the sum of the $ a'$s so far $ b$, and write $(1-a_n)(1-b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $1-a_{n+1}>0$, so the induction hypothesis tells you that

$$(1-a_1)\ldots(1-a_{n+1})>(1-a_1-\ldots-a_n)(1-a_{n+1})\,,$$

and all that remains is to show that

$$(1-a_1-\ldots-a_n)(1-a_{n+1})\ge 1-a_1-\ldots-a_n-a_{n+1}\,.$$

Try multiplying out the lefthand side of that last inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$(1-a_1) \cdots (1-a_n)(1-a_{n+1}) > (1-a_1- \cdots - a_n)(1-a_{n+1})$$ We used $P(n)$ to claim $(1-a_1) \cdots (1-a_n) > 1-a_1- \cdots - a_n$.